# Minimize form disappear

Tags: windows, minimize

I have older application where its forms can be minimize (by __ in top bar of window). Some Windows 10 completely disappear (no small bar on the left down corner)  this form when user press  minimize icon. And there is no way how to restore this minimalized form. I tested it on 6 Win10 computers and 3 works and 3 not. I cant see any correlation what can do this behavior. Is it windows settings, driver update or what?
Thank you

Comment: [mcve] required.

Comment: I cant reproduce it throw the computers. How can I write reproducible example? One Windows installation works in different way then the  second.

Comment: Why can you not produce a [mcve]? Apparently, you have machines, that exhibit the issue. If you are unwilling to put work into this, then we can probably not help.

Comment: Ok, how to reproduce it?

1. Run my application under Win10. Standard c++ builder VCL application contains one sub form.

2. Open this sub form and then minimalize it.

3. On one sort of machines I have small bar on the left down corner and Iam able to restore the position. On the second sort of machine this bar is missing and iam not able to rstore this window to previous size.
                    
All machines are Windows 10 and there is no correlation in Pro/Home/Enterprise. No correlation in updates. 

I don’t understand what can cause this behavioral. Is somebody observing this?